# How to Customise create user wizard in mvc 4 using Membership?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing MVC application. I have used Create user wizard control to create new user using membership in ASP.NET Webforms. Now we switched to MVC So we thought do Shared Authentication to all our Applocation so better to remodify the Code but there is no wizard control in MVC. I need to create our own create user wizard control how to Customise that can anyone please help me.